# ¿Como lograr que la función JSON.stringify se imprima como PHP lo hace?

Tags: javascript, php

Me gustaría imprimir un JSON.stringify de javascript, tal cual lo hace la función json_encode de PHP.
Digamos PHP lo hace así:

```
[{"name": "Jorge"," date":"1999-09-01"}, {"name":"jose","date":"1998-07-23"}]
```

Y javascript lo hace así:

```
{"name":"Jorge","date":"1999-09-01"}{"name":"jose","date":"1998-07-23"}
```

Como puedo lograrlo.

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'data.json',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { search: $('input[type=texto]').val() },
  success: function(data){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var search = JSON.stringify({
   name: data[i].name,
   date: data[i].date
   });
    document.write(search);
    }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Puedes poner tu código JavaScript?. La version que dices es generada en JavaScript no es valida.

Comment: Si, algo falla con lo que dices, no es normal que un array te lo devuelva como dices, eso más bien es 2 json concatenados

Comment: @Animations Así es como lo genera JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/marianom/fpknLcn8/ ... ¿No es lo que estás buscando?

Comment: La respuesta de @rnd es correcta por lo que se puede valorar.

Comment: Les dejo un ejemplo a como yo lo hago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener esa salida necesitas un array de objetos, esto es lo que genera el bloque `[]` del JSON, este array deberia contener objetos asi se generan los bloques `{}`, y por ultimo las comas son parte del array y son agregadas automaticamente cuando tienes mas de un objeto en el arreglo. Luego usando `JSON.stringify` tienes el resultado que necesitas.

Ejemplo:

```js
var obj1 = {"name":"Jorge","date":"1999-09-01"};
var obj2 = {"name":"jose","date":"1998-07-23"};

var array = [];

array.push(obj1);
array.push(obj2);

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(array)
);
```

#### Actualizacion

@AnimationsNow tomando en cuenta el ejemplo que muestras tras la edición, no creo que necesites *stringicarlo* por separado. Bastaría con hacer `JSON.stringify(data)`.

Aver si me explico, la estructura `data` **ya es** un arreglo de objetos, no tiene sentido copiarlo a otro array para luego stringnificarlo.

Hay una excepción, cuando `data` tiene mas campos que no quieres copiar al resultado final. En ese caso podrías hacer algo así:

```
var nuevoArray = []; // declarar un array vacio.
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
   // crear un nuevo objeto y llenar de datos
   var nuevoObjeto = { 
         name: data[i].name,
         date: data[i].date
   };
   // agregar el objeto al arreglo
   nuevoArray.push(nuevoObjeto);
}
var stringfado = JSON.strignify(nuevoArray);
```

Espero te ayude!

Salu2

Comment: Y como podría lograrlo haciéndolo con un bucle for, y pasarlo a una función externa. Ósea digamos tengo mi json elaborado, y quiero retornarlo en una variable para pasarlo a una función externa pero que se genere de igual forma. Digamos tengo mi bucle for `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) return data; función external(data, callback){ callback(data); }` algo así. Perdón sino me explico bien, es que aun no entiendo bien el concepto de javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Si bien la respuesta de @rnd es la correcta, la respuesta para usarlo en el bucle for sería algo así

```
 $.ajax({
     url: 'data.json',
     type: 'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
         search: $('input[type=texto]').val()
     },
     success: function(data) {
         var arregloObjetos = [];
         for (var i = 0; i = data.length; i++) {
             var search = JSON.stringify({
                 name: data[i].name,
                 date: data[i].date
             });
             arregloObjetos.push(search);
         }
         console.log(JSON.stringify(arregloObjetos));
     }
 });
```

Si deseas pasarla a una función externa es mejor pasarla como el objeto que es (arregloObjetos) en lugar del JSON, así puedes acceder a su información por posicion arregloObjetos[0].name,arregloObjetos[0].date... etc etc.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, con tu ejemplo lo solucione. Ahora me gustaría saber como puedo hacerle pasar lo datos a un plugin. Osea pasar el resultado de `JSON.stringify` a esto `$('.content').list({ data: JSON.stringify(data) });` lo intente y no me da resultados.

Comment: Ahora tengo otro problema, me genera una array vacío al final del JSON osea un [], como puedo lograr que no haga eso.

Answer (score 0):

Usando tu código y juntándolo con la respuesta de @rnd, tendrías lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.json',
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { search: $('input[type=texto]').val() },
  success: function(data){
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i = data.length; i++) {
      var search = {
        name: data[i].name,
        date: data[i].date
      };
      array.push(search);
    }
    document.write(JSON.stringify(array));
  } 
});
```